# How to set my native trigger.io module to android only?

Tags: android, native, trigger.io

How can I set my native module to be compatible with android only?

For example, [this module](https://trigger.io/modules/damn_you_form_assist/current/) is set to work only with iOS. How can I do the same for my module to be android only? I can't find in docs any references on how to do this.

Comment: If you're talking about the notice in Trigger toolkit to upload the iOS binary file as well, you just need to remove the /ios folder in /module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Antoine van Gelder, from Trigger.io support:

> We don't have an option to set a module project as Android only.
>
> However, if you don't want to create an Android version of the module
>   you can simply:
>
> - Update the Android inspector
> - You'll now be able to upload the module.
>
> Please note that you won't be able to publish the module and make it
>   publicly available if it does not support both platforms.